# Java: Convert bit string to byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, bytebuffer

I want to write a bit string into a byte array such that the byte array literally contains the bitstring

I have a String with value "10000110" and I want to convert this into a byte array with length 5. I want the resulting byte array to store exactly this bit string, so code_word_array[i] is 0 for i=0,1,2,3 and "10000110" for i = 4

```
byte[] code_word_array = ByteBuffer.allocate(5)
        .putInt(Integer.parseInt("10000110", 2))
        .array();
```

What I'm getting with this code is code_word_array[i] is 0 for i=0,1,2,4 and -122 for i=3. Why is this value not stored in the last byte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your code to say the value needs to be stored in the last byte. As ByteBuffer uses big endian by default, the value is in the 4th byte.

I would just use a byte[]

```
byte[] code_word_array = new byte[5];
code_word_array[4] = (byte) Integer.parseInt("10000110", 2);
```

or

```
code_word_array[4] = 0b10000110;
```